# need to add and remove active class from same list item

Tags: jquery

This code is adding Active class on clicking and If i am clicking on another list it is working fine but if I am clicking again on same link it is not removing active class from it. Please help me out.

Thanks in Advance.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.menulink a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisList = $(this).next();
    thisList .toggle();
    $('li.menulink div').not(thisList).hide();
    $('a').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    //$(this).removeClass("active");
});

}); 

<ul class="allcategorymenu">
            <li class="menuheading menulink"><h1>All Categories</h1></li>
            <li class="mobile menulink"><a href="#"><span>Mobile &amp; Accessories</span></a>
            <div class="submenu" style="display:none;">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="1.html">All Jewelry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="2.html">Diamond Jewelry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="3.html">Silver Jewelry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pearl Jewelry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fashion Jewelry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gemstone Jewelry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Spiritual Jewelry</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            </li>
            <li class="mens menulink"><a href="#"><span>Men's Apparel</span></a>
            <div class="submenu" style="display:none;">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="1.html">All Jewelry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="2.html">Diamond Jewelry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="3.html">Silver Jewelry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Pearl Jewelry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fashion Jewelry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gemstone Jewelry</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Spiritual Jewelry</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("li.menulink a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var thisList = $(this).next();
    thisList.toggle();
    $('li.menulink div').not(thisList).hide();
    $(this).toggleClass('active ');
    $('a.active').not(this).removeClass('active ');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YPRq4/2/)**

Comment: I think it is not working as my requirement.. it is still showing active class on the menu. help will be much appreciated.

Comment: If I click on 1st menu it will be active and it will add active class in a href but if I will click again on 1st menu it will not removing the active class. Please suggest accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li.menulink a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var $this = $(this),
            thisList = $this.next();
        thisList.toggle();
        $('li.menulink div').not(thisList).hide();
        $('a').not($this).removeClass('active');
        $this.toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

This code will remove the active class from all of the `<a>` tags that are not the clicked one, then toggle the active class on that one. Your existing code stripped the class from all anchor tags then added it to the active one whether it was clicked or not.